# How can I send multiple emails to same person within one list?

Tags: email, list, upload

I need to send out voucher codes via email and some contacts have more than one code and therefore need to receive the email multiple times. The contact exist multiple times in the list I upload but  only gets uploaded once. How can I allow multiple uploads of the same email address?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the functionality you have implemented for this email creation?

Comment: It is a manual send.  We have created the email including fields such as code, expiry date and value. We then tried to upload a list of 300 contacts but it only imported 135 due to duplicate addresses. However the codes for these people are different from email to email and therefore need to be sent separately. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue lies with what you have chosen as the unique identifier for each record. I.E the "Primary Key"

If you're using data extensions you'll need to ensure that your "Primary Key" is not the email address.

If you're using lists you'll need to ensure that your "Subscriber Key" is not the email address.

Either way your duplicate email addresses are being excluded because SFMC is recognising that there are duplicate records that need to be excluded because your using the email address as a unique identifier for these records.